# Book about a dragon mage and a dragon queen who stays in her egg

Tags: story-identification, dragons, wizards

Okay so there is this book I am craving to read but I cannot remember the title, author, or any of the character names. All I remember is that it is a series and the first book is a about a boy who is a mage/magician and helps a dragon escape by shrinking the dragon down to fit between the cage bars and the Dragon Queen rules from inside her egg and clams that the human mage will help save them from someone/something. All I remember from the second book is that there is a girl with a dragon living inside her and the main character from the first book has to get it out of her before the dragon takes over her mind.

I can say I read it about five years ago. It was written in American English. All I can say for plot points is that I think it was the dragons trying to fix their relationships with humans after some horrible event that was caused by the villain happened. I think a war perhaps.

Comment: I can say I read it about five years ago. It was written in American English. All I can say for plot points is that I think it was the dragons trying to fix their relationships with humans after some horrible event that was caused by the villain happened. I think a war perhaps.

Comment: Probably a useless comment since OP hasn't been back in two years, but possibly the Dragons of Laton series?